# Get the Username of the Client machine in PHP

Tags: php, apache

I have a web page in PHP which need to start an GUI application in windows 7. Both the application to be started and the apache service runs in the same machine. Apache runs a service started by administrator. Now my machine has LDAP authentication, where many users will login into the machine, open the web page. The web page will start the GUI application by using SCHTASKS, so the application starts as a local user who currently logged in. Now I want to store the user who started the application, i.e the current user who logged in using PHP. I used getenv('username'), 'whoami' everything is giving administrator because Apache is executed by administrator. Is there any way to get the name of the user who logged in using PHP ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "by using SCHTASKS, so the application starts as a local user who currently logged in" - are you sure about that? Exactly how is this done?

Comment: @VolkerK shell_exec('SCHTASKS /F /Create /TN _notepad /TR "notepad.exe" /SC DAILY /RU INTERACTIVE /IT');
 shell_exec('SCHTASKS /RUN /TN "_notepad"');
 shell_exec('SCHTASKS /DELETE /TN "_notepad" /F');

Comment: Not terribly familiar w/ Windows server, but you will probably need to have the user authenticate against the web app itself. (Which you can do via the same LDAP credentials.) Neither Apache nor PHP are going to inherently know anything about the user running the browser that's hitting it.

Comment: The HTTP protocol doesn't send information about the client user.

Comment: There might be some Windows-specific way for the application to find out information about the user logged into the same machine's GUI, like looking into the registry. But there's nothing in normal PHP or Apache that will help with it, because they're geared to the general case of network clients.

Comment: @Barmar Ok. Thank you. I'll look for windows-specific way of doing that.

Comment: Is this a stand-alone PC? Are you working with a Windows domain?

Comment: @trincot its a stand-alone PC.

Answer (score 0):

You have told us nothing about the operating system (nor the windowing environment) this is running on. You mention 'whoami' hence I assume you are talking about Unix/Linux and the XWindow system.

Unless your HTTP application authentication is closely tied to the OS authentication, you'll need to use something like identify to get the uid of the invoking user(actually identify is preferable to assuming that the identity of the HTTP user is the same as the Unix user).

Having identified the user, you then need to be able to execute programming as that user which means some jiggery Pokery with root access which will create huge vulnerabilities in your system if you don't get it exactly right.

But there's still a piece missing from the puzzle. Unix and Xwindow are multi-user systems. In order to open a window on the users screen, you need to know *which* screen to open it on. I can't think of any way to do that deterministically. You could simply assume that its localhost:0.0 but that's a very messy solution.

It would be simpler to create a downloadable file containing a set of parameters with a custom mimetype which is mapped to a shell script which can parse the file and carry out the required action (it will inherit the uid and $DISPLAY from the browser). Note that this method (with an appropriate shell script will work on other OS too).

BTW this is still extremely dangerous - there's a very good reason why http/browsers make it very hard for a server to invoke processing on the clieñt outside the browser.

Comment: Its clearly mentioned that Operating system is Windows 7

Comment: Missed that. OK, you're stuffed, solving this will require huge amounts of code, and probably won't be secure.

Answer (score 0):

PHP? Not possible.

Javascript sending data TO a php script? That is possible.

PHP is a serverside language, meaning that it will never run on a client machine, at run time, you can only know the things about the client that they have told you, and usually, their username is not going to be one of them.

Javascript on the otherhand, is something you you can run on the clients machine, and using this, you can get the username of the user; from here, you could make an ajax request, posting that information to your php script.

Answer (score 0):

this is a quick and dirty way to get what you want done.

```
<?php
    //create a temporary file with a unique name (to avoid conflicts with other users)
    $tempfile = tempnam("/directory/to/save/info","prefix_");
```

Now we'll create a scheduled task that outputs the username into a file...

```
    shell_exec('SCHTASKS /F /Create /TN "_getuser" /TR "whoami > ""'.$tempfile.'"" 2>&1" /SC DAILY /RU INTERACTIVE /IT');
```

The above will output the domain and username, like: COMPUTERNAME/User
If you just want the username, then replace "whoami" with "echo %USERNAME%" like so:

```
    shell_exec('SCHTASKS /F /Create /TN "_getuser" /TR "echo %USERNAME% > ""'.$tempfile.'"" 2>&1" /SC DAILY /RU INTERACTIVE /IT');
```

And now run the task and delete it

```
    shell_exec('SCHTASKS /RUN /TN "_getuser"');
    shell_exec('SCHTASKS /DELETE /TN "_getuser" /F');
```

Now, we can get the username like this:

```
    $username = file_get_contents($tempfile);
    echo "Ran task as: ".$username;
```

That's it!
Finally.. delete the file

```
    unlink($tempfile);
?>
```